# Can I set a text color for the prompt or text I type to to be different from text generated. using bash konsole

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

when iuse the konsole for a period of time I sometimes have to scrollup to remind myself what has been going on but most of the text is green on black, warnings are purple and error messages are red. 
It would be much easier to find my way around if text I type and or the prompt showed in a different color.

Comment: export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m"